# Is it OK to never call Waker for Future

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I am trying to something like:

```
use std::future::Future;
use std::pin::Pin;
use std::sync::atomic::{AtomicBool, Ordering};
use std::sync::Arc;
use std::task::{Context, Poll, Waker};

use arc_swap::ArcSwap;

struct MyFuture {
    flag: Arc<AtomicBool>,
    waker: Arc<ArcSwap<Option<Waker>>>,
}

impl MyFuture {
    fn change(&self) {
        if let Some(waker) = &*self.waker.load_full() {
            waker.wake_by_ref();
        }

        self.flag.store(true, Ordering::SeqCst);
    }
}

impl Future for MyFuture {
    type Output = Option<()>;
    fn poll(self: Pin<&mut Self>, cx: &mut Context<'_>) -> Poll<Self::Output> {
        let flag = self.flag.load(Ordering::SeqCst);
        if flag {
            Poll::Ready(Some(()))
        } else {
            self.waker.store(Some(cx.waker().clone()).into());
            Poll::Pending
        }
    }
}
```

In my case, `change()` may never be called if there is no change, so wake may never be called. Will this block other futures to be executed?

Comment: @kmdreko updated sorry for confusion

Comment: Appreciated, there were still a couple inaccuracies, but I hope I've updated the code to reflect your intentions. Feel free to revert it if its not right.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is OK for a `Future` to never call its waker. That's what [`std::future::pending`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/future/fn.pending.html) does.

It will of course prevent anything `.await`-ing the future from proceeding, but that will not block the asynchronous executor; it will go poll other tasks. The pending task will be waiting around (potentially indefinitely) waiting for it to be awoken.

As @Finomnis points out, it may not even block other code in the same task from running if used in conjunction with `select!` or `timeout` that have multiple futures that can wake it.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning cancellation also still work even if the waker never gets called, so things like a wrapping [`tokio::time::timeout()`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/time/fn.timeout.html) work without any issue.

Comment: @Finomnis mmm, that's a bit different since with an expired `timeout` the future gets *dropped*, not has its waker forgotten. The waker that was given to the timed-out future can still be called, just not meaningfully since wakers are tied to their task, not the specific future.

Comment: No I mean the other way round - a future that never calls its waker doesn't block things like `timeout`. I just wanted to reinforce that it really is ok to never call the waker, even regarding the topic of cancellation safety :)

Comment: @Finomnis oh, I gotcha now